# Android. call method for children tab in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I have FragmentTabHost with children tabs (Fragment)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mTabHost.addTab(newTabSpec, MainTab.class, new Bundle())
    ... 
}
```

How i can call public method from my MainTab (or other tab)?

```
public class MainTab extends Fragment {
    public void showNews() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and vice versa

how i can call any method from FragmentTabHost inside it children tab (Fragment).

Another words, i need know how get link to any children Fragment than is tab in FragmentTabController. How i can get object "MainTab" inside TabHos?

For example in iOS i cat get first viewcontroller from children tab like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [appDelegate.tabController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1]
```

Is there a similar method in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O'k. I was wrong in concept when try get reference to any fragment or view from another. In android i should use events instead.